# Do all anabolic reactions involve condensation?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, metabolism

I know that condensation is one example of an anabolic reaction (building macromolecules from monomers), but do all anabolic reactions involve condensation? Or is there an example of an anabolic reaction which isn't also a condensation reaction?

Could anyone elaborate on this please?

Comment: Assuming that all valencies of the reactants are satisfied, an anabolic reaction will always involve condensation as some bonds will be broken when a new bond between the reactants is formed.

Comment: We (or at least the school of biochemists with which I associate myself) do **not** talk about individual reactions as anabolic or catabolic, but use these terms for the overall  metabolic pathways. The classification of enzymes by the International Union of Biochemistry is solely by their chemistry — see https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iubmb/enzyme/rules.html. Individual reactions in an anabolic pathway will differ chemically.